# How django works with emberjs?

Tags: django, rest, ember.js, django-rest-framework

someone may help me to figure out what part take EmberJS in a web application? Currently I'm using Django for the back-end and I love it, but I'd like to speed up my applications and after reading a bit of docs, I thought that a front-end framework is what I need. After reading a bit of ember, I saw there are a lot of concept that are the same of Django, like models, routes, templates and so on.

This get me a bit confused, because I always saw a front-end framework something that define the "behaviour". As Jon Duckett says in the book Javascript & JQuery, HTML is for the `content`, CSS for the `presentation`, JS for the `behaviour`. After playing a bit with JQuery & Ajax I've been able to speed up a bit my small applications, but is not enough... A lot of developer are moving to ReactJS, AngularJS, EmberJS to create `real-time web apps` and if waiting 2 seconds for a response was ok in 2010, now end users are accustomed to get real-time response (thanks to google and facebook, just to cite someone).

Some questions:

1) I saw EmbjerJS has models. IS the same concept of models in django? I mean, is possible creating web application only with a front-end framework like EmberJS?
2) Why I need a REST API? If I use a front-end framework like EmberJS, the `JS stuffs` can't be included in the template and rendered by django template system?
3) If I use EmberJS what kind of stack I have in applications? Looks like I need only django models with ORM that talk with the DB, a REST API that retrieve data and a front-end that display those data... but How the data are updated?
4) There are some resource that explain this stack in detail and provide a tutorial like django polls with emberjs or contact form?

Comment: Note that ember and angular, as you pointed out, are overlapping frameworks; I've seen more tutorials on angular / django, but they're going to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

**ember** is front-end JavaScript framework.It provides rich api/features to develop an application quickly. If you want to develop an application with ember, you can use ember as Front-end mvc framework and your business logic(server side) can be in any of your favourite language(java/Groovy) and database is your choice.

**ember** comes with ember data i.e., caching system that caches the data you fetched from business layer to ember framework this way it reduces the round trip to server. Call to your business layer can be done through ajax calls from ember.

A rich set of wrappers provided on this framework example, we call lot of functions on a single String object.